# What is the steps of solution for limit of division of trigonometric functions?

Tags: calculus, limits

Given the $\lim_{x\to \pi} \dfrac{\sin(3x)}{\sin(5x)}$. The answer is $\dfrac 3 5$ but what are the solution steps?

Comment: Write $x = \pi+h$, then you get $\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{\sin (3(\pi+h))}{\sin (5(\pi+h))}$. Using $\sin (\pi+\xi) = -\sin\xi$ then gets you a simpler form.

Comment: Do you want to know how to prove $\lim \limits_{x\to \pi}\left(\dfrac{\sin(3x)}{\sin(5x)}\right)=\dfrac 3 5?$

Comment: Taylor Series? L'Hopital? First principles? We don't know what tools you have knowledge of.

Comment: Simpler - better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use L'Hopital's rule (L.H.):

$$\lim_{x\to \pi} \dfrac{\sin(3x)}{\sin(5x)} \quad \overset{L.H.}{=} \quad \lim_{x \to \pi}\dfrac{\Big(\sin(3x)\Big)'}{\Big(\sin(5x)\Big)'} = \lim_{x\to \pi} \dfrac {3\cos 3x}{5 \cos 5x} = \dfrac {3\cdot 1}{5 \cdot 1} = \dfrac 35$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
Use $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac {sinx}{x}=1$$
and use sin($\pi$-x)=sinx

Answer (score 1):

Put $y=x-\pi$ and observing that $\sin(\theta+n\pi)=(-1)^n\sin \theta$, you have
$$
\lim_{x\to\pi}\frac{\sin(3x)}{\sin(5x)}=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{(-1)^3\sin(3y)}{(-1)^5\sin(5y)}=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{3y\frac{\sin(3y)}{3y}}{5y\frac{\sin(5y)}{5y}}=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{3}{5}\frac{\frac{\sin(3y)}{3y}}{\frac{\sin(5y)}{5y}}=\frac{3}{5}
$$
using the fundamental limit $\displaystyle\lim_{z\to 0}\tfrac{\sin(z)}{z}=1$.

Answer (score 0):

We know that while $x\sim 0$ then $\sin(ax)\sim(ax)$. See [An Infinitesimal Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal) or [Classification of Infinitesimal Functions](http://portal.tpu.ru/SHARED/k/KONVAL/Sites/English_sites/calculus/2_InfinitesimalClass_f.htm) for more details.

Comment: But in this example ${x\to \pi}$

Comment: @RCola: Yes and that is why you should take Daniel's leading hint. :)